# Integration of ZAP with Jenkins error

Tags: jenkins, zap

I am trying to integrate ZAP with Jenkins but I am getting following error

I followed the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Execute+ZAP to configure zap.

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\demo 

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] START PRE-BUILD ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE REPLACEMENT
HOST = [ 127.0.0.1 ]
PORT = [ 8090 ]

ZAP SETTINGS DIRECTORY = [ C:\Users\user\OWASP ZAP ]
SESSION FILENAME = [  ]
INTERNAL SITES = [  ]

CONTEXT NAME = [ Test 114 ]

INCLUDE IN CONTEXT = [ http://abc ]

EXCLUDE FROM CONTEXT = [  ]

STARTING POINT (URL) = [ http://abc ]
REPORT FILENAME = [ JENKINS_ZAP_VULNERABILITY_REPORT ]
REPORT TITLE = [  ]

COMMAND LINE = 
    OPTION : [ -installdir ]
    VALUE  : [ %ZAPROXY_HOME% ]

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] END PRE-BUILD ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE REPLACEMENT

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] CLEAR LOGS IN SETTINGS...
SETTINGS DIR [ C:\Users\user\OWASP ZAP ]
WORKSPACE [ C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\demo ]
CLEARING SETTINGS/LOGS


[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] START BUILD STEP

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] PLUGIN VALIDATION (PLG), VARIABLE VALIDATION AND 
ENVIRONMENT INJECTOR EXPANSION (EXP)
ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ZAP PATH IS MISSING, PROVIDED [ 
 null ]
```

Comment: Did you installed Zaproxy? The doc you provided even specify how to install it (Installation Method).

Comment: For any questions re the ZAP Jenkins Plugin I recommend using the official User Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#%21forum/zaproxy-jenkins - the Plugin maintainer doesnt monitor StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Simon. 
I am able to getrid of this error but I got new API error which i have posted on official User Group: groups.google.com/forum/#%21forum/zaproxy-jenkins